# Docusign RestAPI - Send Notification to another email

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign API and sending documents to a candidate for signing. As an admin of the DocuSign account, I get a notification email when the candidate viewed/signed or declined the document. Now all I want is to send this admin notification email to another email via API.

Any idea?

PS: I have to trigger the notification email while sending the documents to the candidate.

Answer (score 2):

Viewed/Signed notifications are always sent to the sender of the envelope via DocuSign (out-of-the-box), and you cannot use API or any other DS settings to re-direct these email notifications to someone else who is not in the workflow. Instead you can opt for one the below two options:

a. Add that person's email address first in the routing order as Carbon Copy recipient, once that person is in routing order then he/she has access to the envelope's history, and can always open the envelope and check the envelope history to know who viewed or signed the envelope. But in this case also this person will not receive any viewed/signed envelope email notifications,but he/she can receive any declined/voided email notification.
b. Use [DocuSign Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/connect-guide) which is based on publish/subscribe type architecture. Per below screenshot, you can subscribed for interested trigger events, once those events happen then DocuSign will push an XML message to your listener, and once you receive these XML messages then you can use any other email APIs like Gmail etc, to send email notification to anyone interested in receiving such notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those notifications go to the owner of the envelope, so if you're okay with losing them yourself you can set up a Transfer Rule so that the alternate email address holds the envelope and gets the Sender Notifications.

Documentation on Custody Transfer Rules is available here: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custody-transfer